# grouping of similar array items under a parent based on a condition javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```
var textTag = [{text:"3", items:[{name:item1.jpeg}, {name:item2.jpeg}, {name:item3.jpeg}]},
                {text:"2", items:[{name:item1.gif}, {name:item2.gif}, {name:item3.png}]},
]
```

I am trying to get a **result** array that would look like this:

```
text:3
|_ jpeg
    |_item1
    |_item2
    |_item3

text:2
    |_ gif
        |_item1
        |_item2

    |_ png
        |_item3
```

But I have written code that gives me the following output.

```
text:3
    |_ jpeg
        |_item1
    |_ jpeg
        |_item2
    |_ jpeg
        |_item3

text:2
    |_ gif
        |_item1
    |_ gif
        |_item2
    |_ png
        |_item3
```

Please help me to get the desired result

Comment: please add your code.

Comment: what you really want ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some grouping for it.

```js
var textTag = [{ text: "3", items: [{ name: 'item1.jpeg' }, { name: 'item2.jpeg' }, { name: 'item3.jpeg' }] }, { text: "2", items: [{ name: 'item1.gif' }, { name: 'item2.gif' }, { name: 'item3.png' }] }],
    grouped = textTag.map(function (a) {
        var o = {};
        a.items.forEach(function (b) {
            var n = b.name.split('.');
            o[n[1]] = o[n[1]] || [];
            o[n[1]].push(n[0]);
        });
        return o;
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(grouped, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: That's great. I had another question: How can I avoid adding duplicate items in the result: [{ text: "3", items: [{ name: 'item1.jpeg' }, { name: 'item1.jpeg' }, { name: 'item2.jpeg' }] }. Here item1 is repeated twice. Any ideas pls. I will update my code in the mean time and let you know if it is working. Thanks !

Comment: @SAM, please do not change the question. ask a new one, if necessary.

Comment: Ok! Makes sense! Thanks for your help !